# Authenticating Instagram In Swift

Tags: swift, oauth, ios8

I am very new to Xcode and coding.

I am trying to make an app which incorporates instagram.

So far I have been able to direct a user to the Instagram authorization page (in safari) where they can choose weather to authorize the app, but I am unsure on how to redirect the user back to the application once they have approved. I get that it's something todo with the redirect URI, but I'm unsure how to use it and also how to retrieve the access token.

Again, I'm new to Swift/Xcode and sorry if this question sounds dumb, but any help would be great. Ive found other websites that have shown how to do this in objective C, but none appear to be in Swift yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question after researching other workarounds, I ended up using [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth) and configuring it with my client ID and redirect URI.

When the user chooses to authorize Instagram (in my apps settings menu) a browser pops up with the login in page. Once logged in a JSON response is returned which contains the access token and other basic details.

Comment: How to resolve `Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI`?